# Сочетание запятой и тире

Tags: пунктуация

Правильно ли расставлены знаки:
"Раскрывая данный вопрос на таком обыденном материале - разговоре старика и мальчика, автор подчеркивает актуальность рассматриваемой темы".
По правилу обособления приложений при помощи тире второе тире опускается, если на его месте должна стоять запятая, так ведь? Возможно ли сочетание запятой и тире помимо случаев с прямой речью?

Answer (score 2):

В данном предложении знаки следует расставить следующим образом:"Раскрывая данный вопрос на таком обыденном материале - разговор старика и мальчика,- автор подчеркивает актуальность рассматриваемой темы". Приложение имеет уточняющее значение, находится в центре предложения, заостряет особое внимание на том, что это за материал, следовательно, с обеих сторон должно выделяться тире. Запятая же ставится потому, что заканчивается обособленное обстоятельство, выраженное деепричастным оборотом, поэтому здесь вполне уместен двойной знак: запятая и тире. Запятая и тире могут ставится также и при вводных предложениях, если такая конструкция выделяется знаком тире в первой части сложного предложения, например: "Ребята ездили с концертом в Дом инвалидов - они долго не забудут эту поездку,- где их встретили с большой радостью". Тире выделяет вводное предложение, а запятая показывает границу сложного предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так написал:
"Раскрывая данный вопрос на таком обыденном материале - разговор старика и мальчика, - автор подчеркивает актуальность рассматриваемой темы". 
Сочетание тире и запятой вполне возможно. Подробности - в пердыдущем ответе, я в целом присоединяюсь.

А что это за правило об опущении тире на стыке с запятой?

===
10.02.2012
Все, сообразил. Вот как это можно сформулировать "на пальцах".
Тире на стыке с запятой опускается только в том случае, если одновременно выполняются два условия: 1) это второе тире из парного знака и если это парное тире является **внутренним знаком** по отношению к обособляемой запятыми конструкции.
В этом случае по сторгой логике запятая должна бы стоять **после** тире, но это никакмими правилами не допускается. 
В остальных случаях запятаю, видимо, слкдует сохранить:

*При встрече внутри предложения запятой и тире сначала ставится запятая, а затем тире, например: История открытий, изобретений, история техники, которая облегчает жизнь и труд людей, – вот собственно история культуры (Горький); Увы! Моя шкатулка, шашка с серебряной оправой, дагестанский кинжал, подарок приятеля, – все исчезло (Лермонтов).*
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/55.htm

Пожалуй, ваш случай запятой действительно не требует.

Comment: Второе тире опускается:
1)      если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая, например: Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой – акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров; (Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник).
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/45.htm#з_02

Разве мое предложение не подпадает под этот случай?

Comment: Тот же пример из другого пособия (Валгина Н.С. Светлышева В.Н.Орфография и пунктуация: Справочник):
"Приложения могут отделяться одиночным тире (второе тире опускается):
1) если по условиям контекста после приложения стоит запятая: Проходя вдоль своего вагона - нашего временного жилища, увидели мы в окне знакомую физиономию".
http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-024.htm

Comment: Очень может быть, что вы и правы. Я в общем-то не позиционирую себя как большой знаток правил, про эти правила слышал, но не обобщал на данный случай. 
Причем в отношении примеров из Валгиной и Розенталя сомнений нет, там второе тире и не хочется ставить. А вот вашем примере - именно что хочется. Не знаю почему, возможно потому, что без него фраза перестает быть понятной. У Р. и В. приложение действительно только уточняет, у вас же весь смысл - в этом уточнении.

Comment: Это не аргумент в пользу сохранения тире, я просто пытаюсь понять, что меня так в вашем примере смутило, может пригодиться, если будем дальше разбираться. Рекомендацию сохранить второе тире для вашего примера снимаю.

Comment: Согласна, предложение действительно звучит немного коряво, пожалуй, лучше было бы использовать другую конструкцию. Тем не менее иного правила, применимого в данной ситуации, я так и не нашла, следовательно, второе тире все-таки необходимо опустить.

Answer (score 0):

Раскрывая данный вопрос на таком обыденном материале - разговор старика и мальчика,- автор подчеркивает актуальность рассматриваемой темы".

Разговор старика и мальчика - это не приложение, а вставная конструкция. И парное тире в таком случае обязательно. (Если она не обособляется скобками или запятыми.)

Привожу пример:

Он встал и, прихрамывая – он был на протезе, – подошёл к окну (Кав.) – вставное предложение примыкает к предшествующему деепричастию, и запятая ставится после всей этой конструкции;

Если бы было:  *- разговорЕ старика и мальчика -*, то это было бы приложением, которое носит пояснительный характер. Приложение всегда стоит в том же падеже, что и определяемое слово. И тогда вторая запятая была бы не нужна, так как после приложения следует запятая.

Раскрывая данный вопрос на таком обыденном материале - разговоре старика и мальчика, автор подчеркивает актуальность рассматриваемой темы".

По правилу:

второе тире опускается:
если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая:

Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки;